# Importing Gmail contacts to another Google account by Adding a POP3 account

Tags: gmail, import, pop3

I want to import a Gmail account to a Google Apps account. I have tried the recommended method of adding a POP account. POP forwarding is enabled. I get the following message:

> Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
>   Server returned error: "[AUTH] Web login required: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754"

The username and password are NOT the issue as I am able to login to the account with the same credentials.

Is there a setting with the original account that is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

First: Be sure to specify in your email client account settings the proper address, protocol, port and encryption for the connection, as instructed here: http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_POP3_Settings.htm

Second: For what you want to achieve (exporting your list of contacts) google takeout seems to be the best fitting solution. More info: https://www.google.com/takeout/

(In particular, for contacts: https://www.google.com/takeout/#custom:contacts)

Comment: I want to achieve to import all my contacts from old account to the new account.

Comment: So, after you export your contacts following the instructions from the above link, you can import them into another google account using this link: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8301